# Connecting a shaver socket

Tags: electrical, receptacle, uk

I would like to install a shaver socket in my bathroom and the closest power supply is the bathroom light switch.  Instead of lifting all of the loft insulation to find the lighting junction box, is it permissible to take a spur from the bathroom light **switch** to power a shaving socket, which is fitted with a transformer?

Comment: Is the light fixture in the ceiling in the center of the bathroom or is it above the lavatory (usually on the walll)? Do you want the receptacle to power a charger for a battery powered shaver or is the shaver corded so runs on mains? Where is this?

Comment: Do you have a receptacle in this bathroom? Usually it is close to the lavatory. Do you want to have the "shaver receptacle" powered when the light is off (to charge a battery powered device) or will you only be using it when the light is on?

Comment: It is a UK installation and the light switch is outside of the bathroom which powers 4 LED down lights. The switch has an in and out live wire connected to it, while the neutral is connected via a terminal block.  The shaver socket to will supply the power for a battery power device charger so it will need to be on when the light is off.  There is a separate fan switch on the outside of the bathroom so would it be better to take the power from there?

Comment: Is the terminal block for the neutral you refer to on the ceiling or is it at the switch? Are these LED sockets ("down lights") powered by mains (230 V 50 hz) or by low voltage DC? I think you need info from a UK source such as @RedGrittyBrick

Comment: You say you want to get the power from a wall switch rather than from one of the ceiling lights. Do you plan to run the power wire to the shaver inside walls or on the surface? It seems to me it would be difficult to run a power cable inside the walls from a switch to the shaver receptacle, unless it would be in the same stud bay. Would this shaver mount be on the wall just opposite a switch?

Answer (score 2):

The bathroom light switch box might not have a neutral in it, and you need both a hot *and* a neutral to power anything.

In the US in older construction the light switch may be connected to the controlled light with a "switch loop", meaning a line hot on one connection of the switch and a switched hot on the other. The line hot and the switched hot are in  the same cable going to the box with the light fixture. One of these two wires would normally have white insulation, and so is sometimes mistaken for a neutral.

However, sometimes the line hot cable enters in the switch box and in that case there is a neutral in the switch box. In that case one can install a cable leading from the switch box to a receptacle.

Comment: In the US lighting spurs are now required to have neutral wires.  That is still not true in the UK, so the number of wires at that switch is very important.